# Wix Toolset: Successively check conditions

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to check two conditions during installation, but need to check it in series: if condition A is false - show error A, do not check condition B.

In details: I have to conditions checks

- My app is installed
- Version of database schema

If my app is not installed - I need to show an error message and do not check database schema, which leads to unknown error during install.

```
<Property Id="MYAPPINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="MyAppInstalledSearch"
                  Name="MyAppInstalled"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="Software\MyApp\Installed"
                  Type="raw"
                  Win64="no" />
</Property>

 <Condition Message="!(loc.RequireMyApp)">
  <![CDATA[(MYAPPINSTALLED="1")]]>
</Condition>

<PropertyRef Id="GETSCHEMAVERSION"/>
```

GETSCHEMAVERSION is a Custom Action used in other components, which tries to connect to the Database and fails if MyApp is not present on the machine.

How can I check GETSCHEMAVERSION property only in case MYAPPINSTALLED condition pass?

Updated:
GETSCHEMAVERSION Custom Action is used in some other helper applications.

Answer (score 2):

The second custom action, which checks for DB schema, should be conditioned to run only if the app is installed:

```
<Custom Action="CheckDbSchema">MYAPPINSTALLED="1"</Custom>
```

That custom action should set another property, as far as I understand, e.g. `DBSCHEMAISOK` to `1`.

Then the components that depends on the schema to be available can be conditioned with `MYAPPINSTALLED="1" And DBSCHEMAISOK="1"`.

I might be missing the syntax details, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Good point, but the problem is that this custom action is used in many other applications, that also check the database schema. So I cannot hardcode condition when only my app installed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this means: "this custom action is used in many other applications". Could you elaborate? Maybe, edit your question with more code samples?

Comment: A custom action is a call to some code from within the MSI. The conditional part is in the MSI file, as Yan said. The condition is not in the code.